# SNAT to from different source IP's to multiple destination IP's

Tags: iptables, routing, pptp, ip-routing

I have a pptp server which issues a local IP to each user on successful auth.  These IP's are in the range of 10.1.1.2-10.1.1.254.
This all works ok, however I then have a set of 128 public IP's that I want to use with those so that when they are seen on the Internet they have a different public IP (or at least 1 public per 2 private IP's).

I have not got MASQUERADE in the IPTables as this would defeat my point, so I added some POSTROUTING to assign the IP's, but this is not working, can you give me a heads up as to why?

This is my Routing in IPTABLES:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.2  -o enp2s0f0 -j SNAT --to-source 111.222.62.131
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.3  -o enp2s0f0 -j SNAT --to-source 111.222.62.131
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.4  -o enp2s0f0 -j SNAT --to-source 111.222.62.132
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.1.5  -o enp2s0f0 -j SNAT --to-source 111.222.62.132
```

As you can see, I am sharing the public IP's in pairs with the private IP's.  The problem is that some are connecting OK to the pptp server but not routing onto the internet whilst others connect and can route fine.

Here is the output from iptables -t nat -L -v -n:

```
    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1152K packets, 91M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 350K packets, 22M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 26973 packets, 1619K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 26975 packets, 1619K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  303 43577 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.2             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.131
43696 2901K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.3             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.131
 209K   15M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.4             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.132
 642K   41M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.5             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.132
 545K   56M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.6             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.133
 330K   20M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.7             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.133
 528K   38M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.8             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.134
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.10            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.135
 128K 7713K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.11            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.135
46652 3366K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.12            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.136
 110K 7777K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.14            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.137
 164K   16M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.16            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.138
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.17            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.138
 172K   18M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.18            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.139
 1010 66407 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.19            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.139
 170K   11M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.20            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.140
 128K 9770K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.22            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.141
 389K   26M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.23            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.141
 261K   26M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.24            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.142
 480K   34M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.25            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.142
 256K   16M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.26            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.143
19186 1278K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.27            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.143
 507K   32M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.28            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.144
19871 1261K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.29            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.144
 295K   19M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.30            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.145
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.31            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.145
 3721  278K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.32            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.146
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.33            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.146
 515K   32M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.34            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.147
41889 3145K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.35            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.147
 630K   45M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.36            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.148
 131K   13M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.38            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.149
 275K   18M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.39            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.149
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.40            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.150
 118K 7865K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.41            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.150
 589K   48M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.42            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.151
16463 1175K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.43            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.151
58869 4170K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.44            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.152
31771 2058K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.45            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.152
 167K   15M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.47            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.153
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.48            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.154
 5316  360K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.49            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.154
98939 6896K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.50            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.155
 790K   69M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.51            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.155
64745 4131K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.52            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.156
89317 6077K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.53            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.156
 251K   18M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.54            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.157
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.55            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.157
24222 2088K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.56            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.158
 127K 8505K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.57            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.158
 400K   27M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.58            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.159
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.59            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.159
 313K   21M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.60            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.160
37024 2416K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.62            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.161
54308 3610K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.63            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.161
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.64            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.162
 420K   26M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.65            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.162
93274 8624K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.66            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.163
 207K   14M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.67            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.163
 103K 6942K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.68            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.164
 234K   20M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.69            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.164
 130K 8657K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.70            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.165
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.71            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.165
36398 3140K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.73            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.166
97306   15M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.74            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.167
 2275  143K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.75            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.167
 404K   35M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.76            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.168
32052 2056K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.77            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.168
28211 2045K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.78            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.169
54749 3809K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.80            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.170
  786 52297 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.81            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.170
27780 1898K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.82            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.171
 195K   13M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.83            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.171
 1466 97841 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.84            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.172
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.85            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.172
22968 1526K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.86            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.173
56645 3705K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.87            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.173
13654 1125K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.88            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.174
 148K 9979K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.89            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.174
 514K   94M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.90            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.175
18243 1235K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.91            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.175
30617 2214K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.92            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.176
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.93            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.176
31116 2061K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.94            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.177
   74  4974 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.95            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.177
 3482  215K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.96            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.178
90743 5996K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.97            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.178
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.98            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.179
91806 5965K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.99            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.179
 4243  287K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.100           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.180
10963  711K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.101           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.180
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.102           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.181
 373K   23M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.104           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.182
 120K 7599K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.105           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.182
 224K   15M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.106           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.183
 6730  434K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.107           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.183
 7337  473K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.108           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.184
 4096  328K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.109           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.184
1326K  125M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.110           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.185
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.111           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.185
96620 6447K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.112           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.186
 528K   34M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.113           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.186
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.114           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.187
 2247  149K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.115           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.187
....
 355K   31M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.204           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.232
 157K   11M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.205           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.232
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.206           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.233
 244K   16M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.207           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.233
37067 2526K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.208           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.234
 322K   19M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.209           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.234
 506K   32M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.210           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.235
 899K   78M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.211           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.235
 422K   26M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.212           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.236
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.213           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.236
 431K   28M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.215           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.237
 839K   75M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.216           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.238
 673K   43M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.217           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.238
 571K   40M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.218           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.239
 293K   23M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.219           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.239
 582K   37M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.220           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.240
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.221           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.240
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.222           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.241
11039  758K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.223           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.241
 106K 7021K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.224           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.242
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.225           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.242
 391K   24M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.226           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.243
 588K   37M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.227           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.243
 427K   27M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.228           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.244
 315K   20M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.229           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.244
28029 2421K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.230           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.245
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.231           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.245
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.232           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.246
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.233           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.246
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.234           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.247
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.235           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.247
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.236           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.248
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.237           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.248
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.238           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.249
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.239           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.249
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.240           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.250
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.241           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.250
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.242           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.251
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.243           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.251
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.244           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.252
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.245           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.252
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.246           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.253
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.247           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.253
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.248           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.254
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.249           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.254
 1416  155K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.79            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.169
 2178  266K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.72            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.166
 1745  224K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.132           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.196
  351 66601 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.61            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.160
22542 1519K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.37            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.148
 2528  248K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.190           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.225
50795 3156K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.214           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.237
 8893  688K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.15            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.137
 2262  308K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.188           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.224
27080 1630K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.157           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.208
41620 2742K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.127           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.193
  170 10545 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.46            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.153
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.124           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.192
11838 3173K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.21            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.140
59117 3942K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.103           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.181
 154K   16M SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.176           0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.218
  407 29599 SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.13            0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.136
 2666  223K SNAT       all  --  *      enp2s0f0  10.1.1.9             0.0.0.0/0            to:111.222.62.134
```

And from iptables -L FORWARD -v -n:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 9052M packets, 10T bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  28M   53G ACCEPT     all  --  enp2s0f0 ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  27M 3429M ACCEPT     all  --  ppp0   enp2s0f0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

And from ip rule ls && ip route ls

```
0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
default via 111.222.62.129 dev enp2s0f0 onlink
10.1.1.4 dev ppp135  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.5 dev ppp14  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.6 dev ppp117  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.7 dev ppp60  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.8 dev ppp99  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.9 dev ppp92  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.11 dev ppp179  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.13 dev ppp143  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.14 dev ppp42  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.15 dev ppp164  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.16 dev ppp17  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.18 dev ppp82  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.19 dev ppp63  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.20 dev ppp153  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.21 dev ppp1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.22 dev ppp155  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.23 dev ppp134  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.25 dev ppp88  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.26 dev ppp56  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.27 dev ppp75  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.28 dev ppp160  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.29 dev ppp171  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.30 dev ppp59  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.32 dev ppp13  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.34 dev ppp36  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.35 dev ppp146  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.36 dev ppp18  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.37 dev ppp103  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.37 dev ppp37  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.38 dev ppp104  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.39 dev ppp23  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.41 dev ppp31  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.42 dev ppp158  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.43 dev ppp121  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.44 dev ppp132  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.46 dev ppp138  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.47 dev ppp79  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.49 dev ppp61  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.50 dev ppp87  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.51 dev ppp46  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.52 dev ppp167  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.53 dev ppp166  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.54 dev ppp20  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.56 dev ppp93  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.57 dev ppp118  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.58 dev ppp24  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.60 dev ppp29  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.62 dev ppp52  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.63 dev ppp26  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.65 dev ppp89  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.66 dev ppp125  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.67 dev ppp147  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.68 dev ppp165  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.69 dev ppp112  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.70 dev ppp107  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.73 dev ppp115  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.73 dev ppp96  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.74 dev ppp130  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.75 dev ppp19  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.76 dev ppp3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.77 dev ppp172  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.78 dev ppp184  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.80 dev ppp141  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.81 dev ppp149  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.82 dev ppp188  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
10.1.1.83 dev ppp15  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.1.0
....
111.222.62.128/25 dev enp2s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 111.222.62.130
```

Comment: Post your detailed configuration with `iptables -t nat -L -v -n`, `iptables -L FORWARD -v -n`, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and things like `ip rule ls` && `ip route ls`. With -v switch with iptables you can actually see how much packets was triggered with each of your rules.

Answer (score 3):

As I can see now, from your detailed update, most likely it seems that you don't have those IP's assigned on your local network interface. You've only added **111.222.62.130** on your server. In order for linux S(ource)NAT to work, you must have every IP address you're NAT'ing to (--to-source) to be actually added on your network interface.

Check `ip address help` on how to assign additional IPs to an interface. You must issue `ip address add 111.222.62.X dev enp2s0f0` for every IP you want to have SNAT working for. It will be convenient to write a script to fill those values.

Be aware, that once you'll add those IPs on your local interface, you will "expose" your server via them to the Internet. You might use iptables INPUT table to block unwanted local connections to those IPs. By local I mean only to your server. Those coming through NAT are subject to FORWARD table only.

PS: If that it's not the case, also please check and post your `ip addr ls`.

Comment: Note another useful tool for diagnosing NAT tracked connections is `conntrack` from the `conntrack-tools` package. Running `conntrack -L` provides detailed output showing exactly what sessions are being tracked and the IP addresses involved.

Comment: I think they are all added:` inet 111.222.62.130/25 brd 111.222.62.255 scope global enp2s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 111.222.62.254/25 brd 111.222.62.255 scope global secondary enp2s0f0:254
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 111.222.62.253/25 brd 111.222.62.255 scope global secondary enp2s0f0:253
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 111.222.62.252/25 brd 111.222.62.255 scope global secondary enp2s0f0:252
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: I have a script that adds them all:

'for (( i=254; i > 130; i-- ))    ; do     ifconfig enp2s0f0:$i 111.222.62.$i netmask 255.255.255.128 broadcast 111.222.62.255; done'

Comment: The problem is that only some of the users can't get an internet routing.  But the failing IP's are not in a sequence so it can't be pointing to an issue with what you are explaining.  Maybe I should clear all iptables and start again.  Basically all I want to do is give people a private IP from chap-secrets and a public IP from the 128 range of IP's available, but some can share those public IP's, I can't use Masquerading because they would all come from the main IP instead of the range, is that correct?

Comment: Well I couldn't know that you've added those IPs because you cut that from your route output. :)
Yes, MASQUERADE will just pick first of the IPs on your interface.
I think then the problem might be in your routing. I don't like that 'onlink' attribute on your default route. That should be set only for those routers which are not in your subnet which is not the case.